# Sencha Touch locale file issue

Tags: sencha-touch

Ok, my file structure looks like the following:

http://imgur.com/BInIbEY

And it seems to be building fine without changing everything like i did before.

Now i have an issue with ext-lang-es.js. Is the localization file i found somewhere in the forums that worked great:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {Ext.Date.dayNames = [
'Domingo',
'Lunes',
'Martes',
'Miercoles',
'Jueves',
'Viernes',
'Sabado'
];




Ext.Date.monthNames = [
'Enero',
'Febrero',
'Marzo',
'Abril',
'Mayo',
'Junio',
'Julio',
'Agosto',
'Septiembre',
'Octubre',
'Noviembre',
'Diciembre'
];




Ext.Date.monthNumbers = {
'Jan': 0,
'Feb': 1,
'Mar': 2,
'Apr': 3,
'Maj': 4,
'Jun': 5,
'Jul': 6,
'Avg': 7,
'Sep': 8,
'Okt': 9,
'Nov': 10,
'Dec': 11
};




Ext.Date.getShortMonthName = function(month) {
return Date.monthNames[month].substring(0, 3);
};




Ext.Date.getShortDayName = function(day) {
return Date.dayNames[day].substring(0, 3);
};




Ext.Date.getMonthNumber = function(name) {
return Date.monthNumbers[name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1, 3).toLowerCase()];
};




//Ext.Date.parseCodes.S.s = '(?:st|nd|rd|th)';




if (Ext.picker.Picker){
Ext.define('Ext.picker.Picker', {
override: 'Ext.picker.Picker',
config:{
doneButton: 'Listo' ,
cancelButton: 'Cancelar'
}
});
}




if (Ext.picker.Date) {
//debugger;


Ext.define('Ext.picker.Date', {
override: 'Ext.picker.Date',
config:{
doneButton: 'Listo' ,
cancelButton: 'Cancelar',
dayText: 'Dia',
monthText: 'Mes',
yearText: 'A&ntilde;o',
slotOrder: ['day', 'month', 'year'] 
}    
});
}




if(Ext.IndexBar){
Ext.define('Ext.IndexBar', {
override: 'Ext.IndexBar',
config:
{
letters: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
}
});
}




if(Ext.NestedList){
Ext.define('Ext.NestedList', {
override: 'Ext.NestedList',
config:{
backText: 'Volver',
loadingText: 'Cargando...',
emptyText: 'Sin registros'
}
});
}




if(Ext.util.Format){
Ext.util.Format.defaultDateFormat = 'd/m/Y';
}




if(Ext.MessageBox){
Ext.MessageBox.OK.text = 'OK';
Ext.MessageBox.CANCEL.text = 'Cancelar';
Ext.MessageBox.YES.text = 'Si';
Ext.MessageBox.NO.text = 'No';
}
});
```

but now i get "Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'Ext.picker.Date', 'Ext.picker.Picker'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'app/ext-lang-es.js', 'app/ext-lang-es.js"
after building the app

So... what did i do wrong? should i put the locale file somewhere else? I also tried adding it to the "js" section of app.json, but it's the same...